# Javascript DOM editting works only below a certain element

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, addeventlistener, setattribute

So I have this javascript code:

```
var HttpClient = function() {
                this.post = function(aUrl, param, aCallback) {
                    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    var url = aUrl;
                    var params = param;
                    http.open("POST", url, true);
                    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200) {
                            aCallback(JSON.parse(http.responseText));
                        }
                    };
                    http.send(params);
                }
            };                 
    function setmain(node) {
                    if (node.getAttribute("disabled") !== "disabled") {
                        var clientset = new HttpClient();
                        clientset.post("<?= $domain ?>include/admin/setmain.php", "id=" + node.getAttribute("pid") + "&token=<?= $_SESSION["Token"] ?>", function (response) {
                            if (response[0] === "216") {
                                node.innerHTML = "ez a fő kép";
                                node.setAttribute("id", "unsetmain");
                                node.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
                                var unsetnode= document.getElementById("unsetmain");
                                unsetnode.setAttribute("id", "setmain");
                                unsetnode.removeAttribute("disabled");
                                unsetnode.innerHTML = "legyen fő kép";
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            var setelements=document.getElementsByName("setmain");
            for (var j=0;j<setelements.length;j++){
                setelements[j].addEventListener("click", function () {
                    setmain(this);
                }, false);
            }
```

and for example this HTML:

```
<button type="button" name="setmain" pid ="100" id="setmain" > legyen fő kép </button> </br>
<button type="button" name="setmain" pid ="101" id="unsetmain" > ez a fő kép </button> </br>
<button type="button" name="setmain" pid ="102" id="setmain" > legyen fő kép </button> </br>
<button type="button" name="setmain" pid ="103" id="setmain" > legyen fő kép </button> </br>
```

The setattribute and inner html function only works on the buttons which is below the the button with id "unsetmain". The onlciklinstener function call is working the HTTP post gets sent but the buttons which is above the "unsetmain" doesnt change anything. There is no error in the console.

Comment: `id` has to be unique in the whole document.

Comment: now i only use the sunsetmain id and no setmain id because its useless but nothing changed